# Float pointer returning a negative value

Tags: c, void-pointers

Why is the value at the address of the float pointer coming to a negative number?

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    float b= 23.66;
    char c='A';
    void *ptr;
    ptr=&b;
    //printf("%d\n", ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *(float*)ptr); // this line here 
    //printf("%d\n", (float*)ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` expects an `int` argument, but the type of `*(float*)ptr` is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier is for integers. Use `%f` for floats.